# {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Microsoft word COM - Access Denied

Tags: microsoft-office, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall Microsoft Office 2003, but I'm getting the following error:

> Can't access class id - {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, permission denied

I'm an administrator on the server. When I look up this key in regedit, I get the same error. If I try it under DCOMCNFG, all the options related to this keys are disabled.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

> {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

That's the class id (CLSID) for "Word.Application" (version independent ProgId).

Permission denied could be from:

- The registry
- A file

Start by looking, with `regedit`, at the ACL on the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` key. If you use the advanced button from the permissions dialog you will be able to see the source of the access control entries (ACEs): there they're all inherited.

If your ACL is not all inherited I would suggest deleting all the non-inherited entries and ensuring include inheritable permissions is selected (and replace on child keys).

ACL here is:

- Administrators: Full control
- SYSTEM: Full control
- Users: Read
- Creator Owner: Special

Comment: Richard, Thanks a lot for the quick response. yes, its related to word app. When i try to access this registry key or changing any option, it shows error: 'Unable to save permission changes on <key> access is denied.' I looked up the advance tab and it has the ACL inherited to it. I don't know much about windows ACL, so can you please suggest me how do i enable edit/delete setting on this key. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Deepak: That error would indicate you are not an administrator (or on Vsita/Win7 an administrator but not elevated).

Comment: I'm logged in as admin. well, i cleaned up the registry using cclearner and removed office installation using microsoft office uninstaller. Now i can access the key 'HKEY_CLASSSES_ROOT\CLSID\{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'. But now when i try to install the office, it show me error to denied permission to key:''